# How to make the url from APIGateway to AWS Lambda was available only from a certain domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have such a configuration of a serverless application: Route53, CloudFront, S3Bucket, APIGateway, Lambda.
 The frontend makes a call to the Lambda function via the API. Accordingly, the URL from the API is practically freely available.
 An attacker can get it and call many times the Lambda function directly.
 How to Make, URL from API causing Lambda accessible only in case of a call from a particular domain?
 That is, I need to configure the APIGateway so that it responds only to a specific Origin header. How to do it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be quite simple. In the Request Method of my API, I added `Request Validator -> Validate query string parameters and headers`, and `HTTP Request Header - "Origin"` in which I specified the required domain (`https://example.com`).
Also did `Enable CORS` and added "Origin" to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`, and ``` Access-Control-Allow-Origin specified``https://example.com ```
And when I called the API from the client, I passed `Access-Control-Request-Headers: Origin` (although maybe it was not necessary).
As a result: the API that calls the Lambda function, when called directly (from the browser or using curl) produces: {"message": "Missing required request parameters: [Origin]"}.
When called from another, not allowed domain, it gives: "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value `https://example.com` that is not equal to the supplied origin".
But when called from `https: //example.com` API is triggered and the Lambda function is started, which was required.

Comment: "... and HTTP Request Header - "Origin" in which I specified the required domain (https://example.com)...." How you do that???, please put some more details...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like what you want is a [Custom Authorizer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html). You create an aws lambda that checks the appropriate headers and then allow/reject the request. The result is then cached as well.

However, you'll want to setup some sort of authentication like AWS Cognito as well to verify who is calling your API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however: although the solution proposed by you deserves attention, but for my task this will be too complicated. I do not need authorization, I just need to check the calling host.